# Getting error on connecting to mysql with DataSource in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

Getting this exception on trying to connect to mysql!

Please don't mark this as duplicate, I tried everything in every thread I found on this, but nothing helped me.

Not using DataSources doesn't help either!
This is part of my plugin for the JTS3Servermod.

> Exception in thread "Soulsbot" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/mysql/jdbc/jdbc2/optional/MysqlDataSource

The error is in the first line of the code

I have installed the Drivers etc correctly added the newest libraries to my Workspace in eclipse.

I am running this on Debian8. On another User using spigot it worked.

```
            MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
            dataSource.setUser(username);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);
            dataSource.setServerName(host);

            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

Full error message:

```
Exception in thread "Soulsbot" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/jdbc2/optional/MysqlDataSource
    at net.mysticsouls.TeamSpeakBot.utils.NameUUIDUtils.connect(NameUUIDUtils.java:36)
    at net.mysticsouls.TeamSpeakBot.utils.Updater.start(Updater.java:11)
    at net.mysticsouls.TeamSpeakBot.TeamSpeakBot.activate(TeamSpeakBot.java:45)
    at de.stefan1200.jts3servermod.JTS3ServerMod.e(Unknown Source)
    at de.stefan1200.jts3servermod.JTS3ServerMod.b(Unknown Source)
    at de.stefan1200.jts3servermod.i.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

pom.xml from Maven:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TeamSpeakBotMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>TeamSpeakBotMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: is the required jar in the classpath?

Comment: @Janar yes! I added the mysql connector to build path libraries

Comment: Please show the commandline used to execute your application.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ist a plugin for JTS3Servermod and rund by a normal Screen command

Comment: I have no idea what JTS3Servermod is, but the error suggests you haven't configured its classpath correctly. Note that in most ways of building a Jar, the dependencies are not included (and they shouldn't).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel how do i include them?

Comment: What do you use for dependency management? gradle, maven, ant? Please add dependencies configuration file to provide more context of your problem.

Comment: @MedvedevV. Maven

Comment: Cool. Can you provide your pom.xml?

Comment: @MedvedevV. I added it above it has no dependencie yet

Comment: well, that explains everything. you need to add <dependencies> section to your pom.xml and list there all dependencies, including mysql drivers.

Comment: @MedvedevV. I changed my pom.xml to the one shown above. It still isn't working and im getting the same error. Im new to Maven maybe i've done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add appropriate [jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) to classpath.

Comment: i added the mysql connector to build path libraries

Comment: @Gerolmed how exactly you've done it? Are you using build tools or it's just eclipse project?

Comment: i clicked Properties > Libraries > add external jars

Comment: I am making a plugin for JTS3Servermod

Comment: can you check Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries? Maybe you added more than one jar

Comment: Do i Need to select the jar under Order and Export?